# Herkoku "must sleep 6 hours in a 24 hour period", showing custom text?

Tags: node.js, heroku, handlebars.js

Heroku [says](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) (free)

> Must sleep 6 hours in a 24 hour period

Ok, that´s fine.

But can I influence the message or any text shown to the user like: "Hello user, unfurtunately the the website needs some rest, please try again from 6 a.m to 2 a.m ".

I can influence the uptime, because of sending a ping every 20 min.

I just found [this](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/5/7/heroku-free-dynos):

> ... free dynos are allowed 18 hours awake per 24 hour period, and over the next few weeks we will begin to notify users of apps that exceed that limit ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a CDN you could create a scheduled task that replaces the root page by a static page at a certain time of day, make sure the CDN updates to that page, and then spin down the app for 6 hours.

The docs for CloudFlare might be a good place to start learning how a CDN works and how to set it up (see: [CloudFlare Support > Getting Started](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/categories/200275218)). Of course you could also use a different Content Delivery Network (CDN) service.

Comment: but the server will not be avaible within that 6 hours of sleep right, so it does not matter which pages I have stored on my heroku app, because he will sleep and therefore not able to call anything on the server ?

Comment: For the time you spin down your heroku app, nothing that is requested from the server will be available. That's why you'd need to channel all requests via a CDN for that period, as it will serve all the (static) content without need to access your server. (But I'd suggest to pay the US$ 7 per month for a Heroku Hobby dyno instead.)

Comment: can you send me some more informations(links), because I don't know how t0 exactly do that ?

Comment: I've edited my original answer including a link to the explanation of how CDNs work and how you'd set them up. Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, I asked someone from the cloudflare tech support and he said it is not possible, at least he does not exacly know what you meant. I got that account on clou flare everything is set up on cloudflare. But In your first paraghraph there are two points which are unclear to me, on the one hand "replaces the root page by a static page"(replace the routes in my app to the static file on another server ?) and on the other hand the more complicated thing how to make "make sure the CDN updates to that page", you ment using expires headers ?